# My createAsyncThunk doesn't work with my api function

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have this in postsSlice

```
export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/getPosts',
async (thunkAPI)=> {
    const response = await api.fetchPosts()
// const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3002/api/posts').then(
//         (data) => data.json()
//     )
return response.data
```

})

and commented response works fine but const response = await api.fetchPosts() doesn't work properly, it sends me errors that posts.map is not a function but data Arrays looks fine

api.fetchPosts() looks like this

```
import axios from "axios"
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:3002/api"})

API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
   if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token')).token
    }`
}
return req
})



export const fetchPosts = () => API.get(`/posts`)
```

[image: errors]

here is where map function is

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import CardMain from "../../components/CardMain/CardMain";
import {createPost, getPosts} from "../../redux/features/posts/postsSlice"

const Main = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const {posts} = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts())
}, []);
console.log(posts)

return (
    <div>

        <div>
            {
            posts.map(user=>(
               <CardMain post={user} key={user._id}/>
            ))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `console.log` you can see, that `posts` is actually an object in the form `{ data: [ .... ] }` - you cannot `.map` on an object.

So either you need to `return response.data.data` in your thunk, or do `posts.data.map(...` instead of `posts.map(...` (or change your api method to directly return correct unnested data)